# how to solve error QContact.h is not recognized in Qt

Tags: qt, contacts

In our Qt application we want to use contacts from the phonebook. the problem is that QContact.h is not recognized. what might be the problem? Thanx

Answer (score 0):

To use contact with Qt I think you are using QtMobility. Have you set the *.pro? It is often because you didn't set the *.pro file to use QtMobility.

You should look at this tutorial: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility/samplephonebook.html